# Cannot connect to WiFi with nmcli, although secrets are provided

Tags: linux, wifi, networkmanager, nmcli, wpa

I am using `nmcli` on ArchLinux (version 1.14.5dev+17+gba83251bb-1 from the official package repository) to connect to wifi. This works perfectly for all wireless networks apart from this one Vodafone EasyBox network.

Trying to activate the connection with the correct password gives me the following error message:

```
Passwords or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network 'EasyBox-123456'.
Warning: password for '802-11-wireless-security.psk' not given in 'passwd-file' and nmcli cannot ask without '--ask' option.
Error: Connection activation failed: Secrets were required, but not provided
```

However, `802-11-wireless-security.psk` is stored, as you can see here:

```
$ nmcli con show EasyBox-123456
connection.id:                          EasyBox-123456
connection.uuid:                        <hidden>
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        802-11-wireless
connection.interface-name:              --
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.multi-connect:               0 (default)
connection.auth-retries:                -1
connection.timestamp:                   0
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:                 --
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 --
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        default
connection.mdns:                        -1 (default)
connection.llmnr:                       -1 (default)
802-11-wireless.ssid:                   EasyBox-123456
802-11-wireless.mode:                   infrastructure
802-11-wireless.band:                   --
802-11-wireless.channel:                0
802-11-wireless.bssid:                  --
802-11-wireless.rate:                   0
802-11-wireless.tx-power:               0
802-11-wireless.mac-address:            <hidden>
802-11-wireless.cloned-mac-address:     --
802-11-wireless.generate-mac-address-mask:--
802-11-wireless.mac-address-blacklist:  --
802-11-wireless.mac-address-randomization:default
802-11-wireless.mtu:                    auto
802-11-wireless.seen-bssids:            --
802-11-wireless.hidden:                 no
802-11-wireless.powersave:              0 (default)
802-11-wireless.wake-on-wlan:           0x1 (default)
802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt:      wpa-psk
802-11-wireless-security.wep-tx-keyidx: 0
802-11-wireless-security.auth-alg:      open
802-11-wireless-security.proto:         --
802-11-wireless-security.pairwise:      --
802-11-wireless-security.group:         --
802-11-wireless-security.pmf:           1 (disable)
802-11-wireless-security.leap-username: --
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key0:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key1:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key2:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key3:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key-flags: 0 (none)
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key-type:  unknown
802-11-wireless-security.psk:           <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.psk-flags:     0 (none)
802-11-wireless-security.leap-password: <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.leap-password-flags:0 (none)
802-11-wireless-security.wps-method:    0 (default)
802-11-wireless-security.fils:          0 (default)
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       ""
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         --
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       ""
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         --
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.dhcp-duid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.token:                             --
proxy.method:                           none
proxy.browser-only:                     no
proxy.pac-url:                          --
proxy.pac-script:                       --
```

I tried several things, including restart NetworkManager/wpa-supplicant, the router, and disabling PMF, but nothing worked.

Specifying `--ask` asks me for a password, but gives me the same error message afterwards. Removing and recreating the connection using `nm-connection-editor` didn't work either. It works without any problems on my Android device.

**How can I connect to this Network?**

Comment: My go-to one-liner for nmcli is `nmcli dev wifi con <ssid> password <password>`. I suspect it won't work in your case, but it might be worth trying.

Comment: This one-liner just says "No network with SSID ... found". So it probably requires some configuration before.

Comment: is there any other device that can connect to this network?

Comment: @binarysta Yes there is including another Linux Laptop with the same operating system

Comment: Same issue here. Network is working fine for all other devices. (EDIT, one difference: debian based distro)

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit late but I found a potential workaround. According to the [documentation of nmcli](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html) you can connect to your AP providing a passwd-file with the content of the file:

```
802-11-wireless-security.psk:secret12345
```

and the command:

```
nmcli con up <connection name> passwd-file <filename>
```

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this issue, as I did recently after moving to a new ISP, this message is also caused by a mis-spelled password in `nm-connection-editor`. This was true for both Oracle Linux 7 and Oracle Linux 8.